# Cleaning up certain sections of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Im using the following code to import a csv that has two columns - account & phone:

```
$csv = array();
$file = fopen('import.csv', 'r');

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    $csv[] = $result;
}

fclose($file);
```

The results look something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5182334
            [1] => (360) 293-7786
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8372855
            [1] => (360) 755-3237
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8373250
            [1] => (360) 873-8853
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8373226
            [1] => (360) 588-1905
        )
)
```

What I need to do is loop through the array and clean up the phone numbers removing spaces, parans, etc.  I know how to do the clean up but can't figure out how to loop through the array to do said cleaning.

Comment: Since it seems that the phone number is the second element int he array, just do `$result[1] = cleanup($result[1]);` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map` and `preg_replace` for example.

```
function clean($item) {
   $item[1] = preg_replace('#[^\d]#', '', $item[1]);
   return $item;
}

$csv = array_map("clean", $csv);
```

Or directly in loading phase:

```
$csv = array();
$file = fopen('import.csv', 'r');

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    $result[1] = preg_replace('#[^\d]#', '', $result[1]);
    $csv[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: What happens to the numbers 8 and 9? Should be |[^\d]|

Comment: +1 for using array_map with preg_replace as it's the most appropriate method for this task.

Comment: Thanks, Jakub, loving the loading phase version! Off topic but what do the pipes at the front and rear of the preg_replace represent?

Comment: You're welcome. Here is explanation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. So better is to use `#` instead of pipes (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$arr = array(....); //your array
//Removing '(', ')', ' ' and '-' from the array values.
foreach($arr as $v)
 $v = str_replace(array(' ', '(', ')', '-'), '', $v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = array(' ', '-', '(', ')'); 
foreach($csv as &$line) {
    $line[1] = str_replace($search, '', $line[1]);
}
```